# Nodejs - Mongoose - callbacks work only once

Tags: node.js, mongoose, callback

I am working with callbacks, and it makes the first call (POST), and never work again. I couldn't get any response error in postman.
This is the modal schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird'); 
var ModalitySchema = new mongoose.Schema({   
    name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
    updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

And this is the call in the controller:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Modality = require('../models/modality').Modality;

/** create function to create Modality. */
exports.create = function (req, res) {
Modality =new Modality({name:req.body.name,type: req.body.type});  
Modality.save( function(err, result) {
        if (!err) {
            return res.json(result);
        } else {
          console.log(err);

            return res.send(err); // 500 error
        }
    });
};
```

and the outers of node: 
[image: Outer of node]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was so blind to the point i feel stupid to spend so long with it, i was saving the wrong modal:

```
Modality =new Modality({name:req.body.name,type: req.body.type});  
Modality.save( function(err, result) {....}
```

while in fact it had to be

```
modality =new Modality({name:req.body.name,type: req.body.type});  
modality.save( function(err, result) {....}
```

Answer (score 0):

The server encountered an error. Your model is incorrectly exported, the right way :

> var Modality = require('../models/modality').model('Modality').schema